# Anonymous function and IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, anonymous-function

I have a button in a table cell that when clicked needs to get the text of the first cell in it's row, then place that text into a hidden variable of a form.

Like this:

Button:

```
<button type="submit" class="get-jobid" form="form1" value="Submit">Resolve</button>
```

Form:

```
<form class="get-jobid" id="form1" action="resolve_problem_page.php" method = "get">
     <!--Below is a hidden variable used to send the JobID to the resolution page-->
     <input type="hidden" id="hidden_jobid" name="hidden_jobid" value=""/>
</form>
```

Script:

```
<script>
  $(".get-jobid").click(function() {
    var $row = $(this).closest("tr");// Find the row
    var $text = $row.find(".JobID").text(); // Find the text
    document.getElementById("hidden_jobid").value = $text;
  });
</script>
```

This solution works perfectly and as expected on every browser apart from Internet Explorer. With IE when the button is clicked nothing happens. Using the IE debugging console it shows that when I click the button the page halts and has an orange arrow pointing to the line

```
var $row = $(this).closest("tr");
```

and says "Anonymous function".

Can anyone help me to un-anonymise this function?

I've tried myself but most of that jQuery stuff is over my head, in fact I found the above solution on this site and it works great on everything, apart from IE.

Thank you,
Aaron

Comment: Have you tried `on('click', function(){ ...` instead of `click(function(){...`?

Comment: Please could you show a screenshot of the error? Because as someone who uses IE as primary browser, I have never had an "orange arrow pointing to [a] line"...

Comment: Which version of IE?

Comment: on(click) thing didn't work.

Comment: IE version is 11, screen shot here: http://tinypic.com/r/2iqmr83/8

Comment: Silly question... do you actually have a `<tr>`?  I don't see a table in your HTML at all.

Comment: Yes, it's just much further up the page of code. Like I said it works perfectly on any other browser. IE is just giving me problems.

Comment: "Anonymous function" is not an error message in IE, can you show the real error message, and add that much of code that we can reproduce the issue?

Comment: If that's not an error message then I'm not getting any. The fact is when the button is clicked, the browser should go to another page with "?hidden_jobid=1020" at the end of the url. This is what happens in Firefox, in IE nothing happens at all. I don't know what the problem is.

Comment: Have you created `tr`s or `td`s by setting `innerHTML` or using `.html()` jQuery function?

Comment: Here is a screenshot of the tr's and td's: http://tinypic.com/r/15oz6o1/8

Comment: OK I think I've traced the problem to the buttons. The submit button I have is OUTSIDE the <form></form> tags. Like this: <form id="myform" method="get" action="something.php">
    <input type="text" name="name" />
</form>

<input type="submit" form="myform" />

Comment: Apparently this is a HTML5 thing and doesn't work with IE

Answer (score 0):

Try next() instead of closest("tr").

Comment: next() doesn't work, just breaks it in other browsers that it used to work in.